# Java Synchronized/Thread-safe/'Centralised" Array or an alternative which will be shared by other Threads

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading, parallel-processing, thread-safety

I want to create an array which will be shared between Threads. It means that an array should have an ability to be modified by every thread as well as used by checking the values inside it. The only solution which I could find is to create a synchronizedList.

Is it possible to make/create an **array** which could be (Synchronized/Thread-safe/'Centralised") or in other words shared between threads in Java?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes. Make the array `private`, don't let the reference leak. Create 2 methods `set` and `get` which are *synchronized* and use these methods to modify / get data from the array. As long as all accesses to the array are via these methods and you don't leak the reference of the array, you are good to go. 

PS : You can add new "eventually synchronized" methods in case you want more functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Synchronized list won't help, as you will be able to iterate through the list which is being changed at the moment, ie see the list's unpublished state.

Please, check [CopyOnWriteArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html) It will allow you to change the list atomically and get valid list snapshot every time you iterate/search through it. Drawback is that underlying array is copied on every CopyOnWriteArrayList modification.